# Grails Pagination - Issue not to load images with freewall js

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

GRAILS
Controller

```
def beta() {
        params.max = Math.min(params.max ?: 10, 100)
        params.offset = Math.min(params.offset ?: 10, 100)
        def l = Portfolio.findAllByPublished(true, params)
        int total =  Portfolio.countByPublished(true) 
         withFormat {
            html { 
                [list:l, portfolioInstanceTotal: total]
            }

            json { 
                render l as JSON 
            }
        }

    }
```

GSP template

```
<div class="pagination">
<g:paginate omitPrev="true" omitNext="true" controller="designer" action="beta" total="${portfolioInstanceTotal}" />
</div>
```

[image: Stacktrace]

I also use JQuery with freewall js to append the images in grid. I try to append the images to pagination, but I got errors as u can see on stacktrace.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the rest of the stacktrace please?

Comment: It looks like either params.max or params.offset is returning a string. Can you try parsing it as an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request parameters are Strings. So `params.offset` returns a String.

Calling `Math` method with String as parameter throws an exception.

You should convert the String to int first:

```
params.max = Math.min(params.max.toInteger() ?: 10, 100)
...
```